# Laravel Eloquent Many-to-Many query

Tags: php, laravel

I have `many to many` relationship between two tables for e.g. `lecture` and `students (users)`.

Now if the `lecture` is private or limited to invited users only than `lecture_student` table has entries in it with `student_id`.

`lecture_student` has `student_id` and 'lecture_id' keys.

So if lecture is limited to some students then `lecture_student` will have list of all `user_id` rows in it else it is open for all.

When a user logs in I display list of `Lectures` using following query

```
Lecture::where('user_id', '<>',$logged_in_user->id)
    ->futureLectures() // query scope defined for future lectures only
    ->get()
```

How do I get the lecture for a student where he/she is invited to and also open for all?

Above query gets me all the lectures weather `student` is invited to that `lecture` or not.

I tried `whereHas` but it does not work because `lecture_student` table only has entry in case the `lecture` is limited to some users, in case of open `lecture`, `lecture_student` has not row.

Thank you

Comment: How do you know which lecture is open for all?

Comment: If there is no entry in `lecture_student` table then it is open for all else it is only limited to the inserted `student_id` data.

Comment: I want to display a list of lectures to a student. It included both invited and open for all. For example when user with id `266` logs in, he sees list of all open plus where `266` is invited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [Query Relationship Existence](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) to get the lectures where logged student was invited

```
whereHas('students', function ($query) use ($logged_in_user) {
    $query->where('id', $logged_in_user->id);
})
```

and [Query Relationship Absence](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-absence) with `orDoesntHave`, to get too the lectures that has no related (invited) students.

```
orDoesntHave('students')
```

Do that inside a [Parameter Group](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/queries#parameter-grouping).

```
Lecture::where(function ($query) use ($logged_in_user) {
        $query->whereHas('students', function ($q) use ($logged_in_user) {
                $q->where('id', $logged_in_user->id);
            })
            ->orDoesntHave('students');
    })
    ->futureLectures()
    ->get();
```

Comment: I think this is it. I tried this but did not wrap it under `where` so gave me false result. Checking it now.